# Tricky question for good understanding of CSRF

Tags: security, xss

My friend and I have a pari for beer.

From wikipedia:

> Requiring a secret, user-specific
>   token in all form submissions and
>   side-effect URLs prevents CSRF; the
>   attacker's site cannot put the right
>   token in its submissions

The atacker can use browser cookies indirectly, but he can't use them directly!
That's why he can't put the cookies into the link using `document.write()`

Let us look how the logout link is generated. Is it secure way? Can this GET request be faked?

```
function logout(){
     echo '<a href="?action=logout&sid='.htmlspecialchars($_COOKIE['sid']).'>Logout</a>';
}
```

**sid** is a session ID, generated for every session

on the server side, the following checking is performed:

```
$_GET['sid']==$_COOKIE['sid']
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Absolutely **not**!  Never use session identifiers for CSRF protection.

As far as why?  Well, the answer is simple.  Doing so opens the door for [session hijacking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_hijacking) attacks.  Imagine someone copies and pastes the link for some reason into an email or onto the web.  Now, the person on the other end of the email has the session identifier of that session.  Sure, if they click the link it won't activate the session, but someone who knows what they are doing will still be able to use it.

And don't use a secret cookie either.  Cookies are transmitted on every request.  So the mere existence of a cookie does not verify that the user intended to make the request.

How to do it instead?  Follow the [OWASP recommendations](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet).  Use a unique, random token that's issued on each request and is associated with the session.  Then verify that the token is valid on submission and then **invalidate the token**!  It should be a one-time-use token only.  Have it submitted by the form, and not attached to a link directly...

Comment: @Rook: which part isn't correct?  I never said that it opened CSRF attacks.  Just that using the session identifier in a url/for csrf can open other attack vectors.  And I supplied the best alternative which is to use one-time-use tokens.  So what's not entirely correct?

Comment: I don't think this fully addresses the question at hand.  Just a minor disagreement,  I'm not going to down vote you or anything.  You are welcome to read my answer if you want to know my stance on the topic.

Comment: @Rook: I'm just curious what you thought wasn't correct.  If it's that it doesn't fully address the question, that's fine.  I was just curious if I could improve it (and improve my knowledge).  Unless I'm missing something, our answers are complimentary...

Comment: Ahh, right. In my post, I hadn't considered the possibility of copy+pasting links.

Comment: @ircmaxell oah totally.  I guess what I mean is that yes it *can* lead to session hijacking,  but the only case i see is if you are using http_only cookies and then you have an xss vector.  Also the OP wants a deeper understanding of CSRF,  and its important to note that this technically immune to CSRF.

Answer (score 4):

This prosed security system is **immune to CSRF**.    The reason why this works is because in a CSRF attack the browser keeps track of the cookie,  so *the attacker doesn't need to know the cookie value when he is building the request*.   If this proposed security system where vulnerable to CSRF an exploit like the following Proof of Concept would log out a browser:

`<img src=http://victim_site/index.php?action=logout&sid= />`

Clearly in this case sid needs a value, and an attacker cannot obtain this value without using XSS,  which makes this a moot point.  Using xss an attacker can read a CSRF token to forge requests.  This was used in the [MySpace worm Sammy](http://namb.la/popular/tech.html).

The use of the cookie a valid,  however weaker form of CSRF protection.  One problem is that it totally undermines [http_only cookies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533046%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  Ideally a CSRF token and a session id should be a [Cryptographic nonce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_nonce).  However, it is more secure to have them be separate values.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit**: This answer is at least partially wrong. Using the session ID as a CSRF token *could* lead to session hijacking if, eg, links are copy+pasted around. See ircmaxell's answer and comments.

Yes, because the session ID is both random and associated with the user, it would be an acceptable form of CSRF protection.

That said, it would be *even safer* to use a different random number, on the off chance that malicious JavaScript is able to grab the session cookie (and session ID)… But if I had to choose between “no CSRF token” and “session ID as a CSRF token”, I'd always pick the session as a CSRF token.

The only potential problem with using session IDs as CSRF tokens is: if someone was able to steal a CSRF token, they would also be able to hijack the associated session… But I can't think of a sensible scenario where that would be an issue.

Now, from the discussion on Marc B's answer, below: using a [nonce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_nonce) would provide *other* benefits (like preventing duplicate form submissions)… But it isn't any more secure against CSRF attacks than the session ID (with the one caveat I mention in the first second paragraph).

See also: [CSRF Validation Token: session id safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518313/csrf-validation-token-session-id-safe)

Comment: I will definitely use some other random toked instead of SID. The question was given for brain training )

Comment: The advantage of the methopd given above is that you don't have to generate additional unique tokens for each user and store them in database. It's the way to make app simplier

Comment: Yup, that's what I was thinking when I said “if I had to chose…”. Totally unique tokens would be a bit better, but session IDs don't create any security problems (that I can see), and they are way better than nothing.

Comment: @David: sensible scenario?  1. User shares a link on a website. 2. Browser history (albeit if they get that far, they should have access to the session anyway). 3. Log files on the ISP or Firewall. 4. Referrer headers if the submitted page links somewhere else.

Comment: The session ID is *not* a request authentication token! Both have absolutely different purposes.

Comment: @ircmaxell: ah, good point. I've updated my answer, but unfortunately I can't downvote myself.

Comment: @David: I wouldn't downvote this answer.  There is good info in it.  The only issue lies in edge cases.  So it's not *wrong* (I +1ed)...

Answer (score -4):

And what's to stop someone from editing the HTML that you send them, as well as the cookie, which you've also send them? Both are are under the control of the user.

With firebug I can trivially change the contents of any page, as well as any cookie.

Now, if you'd modified your version so that the SERVER stores that ID, then it would be harder to hack...

```
$_SESSION['form_token'] = 's33krit valu3';

if ($_POST['form_token'] == $_SESSION['form_token']) {
  ... everything's ok ...
}
```

Since the session data is kept on the server, out of the attacker's hands, this is far more secure than trusting the attacker won't think to modify the cookie.

---

You owe your friend a beer.

Comment: Unless I misunderstand, this isn't the attack vector he's trying to protect against. He's trying to make sure that `evil.com` doesn't perform a CSRF attack (for example, by using an `<img src="happy.com/logout.php" />`).

Comment: XSS is including malicious script (or url) on other server's webpage. That means that you can put `<img src="http://example.com?action=logout'/>` on other server's webpage, but you will never guess the SID

Comment: Additionally, your “s33krit valu3” *would* need to be sent to the client (eg, to be used as a GET parameter or a hidden form element), so I'm not sure how it's any safer.

Comment: @Marc B: I believe Dan is concerned about cross site request forgery ie. someone giving you a link http://www.dan's-server.com/?action=logout and making the server log you out (or some other action). When the server needs the correct session ID in both cookies and URL than it's impossible to give you such a link without already knowing your session id.

Comment: It's a nonce, to prevent form replays.

Comment: Even if it's just a logout link above, you can't tell the difference between someone clicking on a logout link, or including it in an `<img>` tag. Either way, your browser's going to "GET" that page and both methods will look identical.

Comment: @Marc: a nonce does have value, and can be used as CSRF protection… But it offers no more *CSRF protection* than a session ID does.

Comment: @Marc: re: `<img>` link: yes, that's correct. Which is why you'd want to use a CSRF token as part of the logout link.

Comment: Read the entire [Browser Security Handbook](http://code.google.com/p/browsersec/wiki/Main) before posting about CSRF.